# Canvas growing larger than container, when both should be exactly the same size

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `canvas` inside a square `main` tag, which is set to `100vh` height (and width). I set the height of the canvas to the `clientHeight` of `main`, but I'm getting a scroll bar in the window, indicating that either `main` or `canvas` (or both) are taller than the viewport. If I set it to `clientHeight - 5` I see no scrollbar. Why is that?

```js
var cnv = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
cnv.width = main.clientWidth;
cnv.height = main.clientHeight;
//cnv.width = main.offsetWidth;
//cnv.height = main.offsetHeight;
//cnv.width = main.getBoundingClientRect().width;
//cnv.height = main.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
main {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
nav {
  background-color: #fffdd0;
}
canvas {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <canvas></canvas>
</main>
<nav>Nav with lots of contents, Nav with lots of contents, Nav with lots of contents</nav>
```

Comment: Not happening for me!! FireFox 68.0.2

Comment: @masoudmanson I'm using Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 (64-bit). Don't you see a scroll bar in the above snippet? And a thin green line below the yellow canvas?

Comment: @masoudmanson The same also happens on Chromium. I removed the scroll bar (overflow:hidden) but the page still moves when I press the End key, when it shouldn't. Strangely, the Home key don't take it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the canvas element has `display: inline;` as the default display property thus sitting on a baseline which is slightly elevated from the bottom of it's parent to create space for [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). Since the canvas is the same height as its parent plus the added baseline spacing at the bottom the result is an overflow. To fix this just add `display: block;` to your canvas.

```js
var cnv = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
cnv.width = main.clientWidth;
cnv.height = main.clientHeight;
//cnv.width = main.offsetWidth;
//cnv.height = main.offsetHeight;
//cnv.width = main.getBoundingClientRect().width;
//cnv.height = main.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
main {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
nav {
  background-color: #fffdd0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <canvas></canvas>
</main>
<nav>Nav with lots of contents, Nav with lots of contents, Nav with lots of contents</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! The scroll bar is gone, but I still can see a thin green line below the yellow canvas. I thought it was because `clientHeight` is integer, so I tried `getBoundingClientRect().height` (which is a float), but the green line persists. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't see the green line, what browser are you on ?

Comment: It appears on Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 (64-bit). But not on Chromium 73.0.3683.75 (Developer Build) built on Debian 9.8, running on Debian 9.9 (64-bit).